# How to read Elastic ip of an aws instance when created through vagrant and chef-solo

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins, chef-infra, vagrant

I am using vagrant with chef-solo for creating and provisioning a test environment, with an elastic ip assigned. I want to read the elastic ip of the test environment and return it to jenkins, where jenkins uses this ip and deploys the war into this machine for a functional testing.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to get the system public IP. You can get the information by accessing the instance metadata. Here is the command by which you can get the public IP associated with your instance.

```
GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/02:29:96:8f:6a:2d/public-ipv4s
```

Change the MAC address as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks linuxnewbee. But i found another way.

$vagrant ssh

$ ec2metadata | grep public-hostname

This command returns publich-hostname ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Now I have to pass this ip to jenkins, which is yet to be done.